# How do you input FEN into Lucas Chess?

Tags: software, fen

How can I input a position into Lucas Chess, in order to view the underlying engine's analysis through Lucas Chess's GUI? The position would be specified in FEN.

Under its menu Tools->PGN, Lucas Chess offers the features of reading a PGN file or pasting PGN. Is there really no simpler way than to create a PGN file with the FEN tag, and get Lucas Chess to read that? That would be a workaround, but it's a clumsy one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

in swedish ,

verktyg(settings probably)-skapa ett schackparti(create a new chessgame or something)-settings-changing the starting position-Klistra in FENställning (paste Fen or something) Done!

Comment: Correct. It's Create your own game, then Utilities->Change the initial position->Paste FEN position. It was hard to find because, for one thing, I don't want to create a game, only set a position up, and for another, I don't want to change the *initial* position. This is not the only Lucas feature where it's not obvious which menu it's under.

Answer (score 1):

"Create your own game" and Ctrl-V.
Then "Help to Move" in the toolbar

Ctrl-K informs about other shortkeys.

To do a continuous analysis of various positions, with kibitzers is a way, if you don't have any Candidates kibitzers, first create one with the engine you want to analyze: Tools, Engines, Kibitzers, and New, Engine, and choose the engine or you leave stockfish. You accept. Then Tools, Create your own game, Utilities, Kibitzers, you choose the created one. In the kibitzer window there is a rocket, you launch it, Ctrl V to indicate the position or you edit it manually, .... (the kibitzer board also allows movements)